# How do we handle unnecessary tag creation?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I edited this question [Asp.Net 5 Music Store Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077264/asp-net-5-music-store-application) to remove the new tag.

How do we handle unnecessary tag creation?

example: [aspnetcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnetcore) when we have [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing it, it is now no longer used. The system removes unused tags every 24 hours, so it will be gone soon enough.

If the user keeps creating the tag, you may want to talk with them. Perhaps they believe a tag synonym is needed.
If you agree that a tag synonym is needed, then either of you can propose it.

Speaking in the general case, if a newly created tag is particularly bad, you can ask here on Meta to have it blacklisted, so that it can't be created again. This is not done often though, as people find ways around blacklists.

But for now, just removing it from the question should have been enough.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was some system in place.

Comment: Also I should add, I think the OP did it in good faith, without realising there was an existing tag.

Comment: @MsYvette I think so too. I'm also glad to see you pointed the OP to the Meta discussion here.